# Odoo 11 : Proper way to upgrade modified addons

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Here are the steps that I must follow to upgrade an addons on Odoo 11 :

**1**. Go to `Apps` tab.
 **2**. Remove the `only Apps` filter (because I upgrade a simple module).
 **3**. Search and find my module.
 **4**. Click on my module to open its panel.
 **5**. And finally Click on upgrade.
 **6**. (optionally) restart the Odoo server...

Do you know a quicker/proper way ?

*(My question is similar to [this one](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/is-there-a-proper-way-to-upgrade-custom-module-in-windows-71244) which dates from 2014 and seems outdated.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Restart the server.
2. open terminal
3. goto odoo directory
4. `sudo su postgres`
5. `./odoo-bin -i addon_name -d db_name`

Use i for install and -u for update the addons.

Comment: I think this works only if he have one database. and he should know that every time here restart Odoo the upgrade happen.

Comment: Plus he will start a new odoo instance.